# Filter array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array using Chakra UI. But the filtering cannot be done correctly.
I have done many tests to make sure that if the problem is in other codes, I can say that the problem is caused by the code below. However, I can share more code with you if you want.

**Note**: The list disappears when the filterText exists, and the listing works correctly when the filterText does not exist. This code belongs to a note taking app. I want to filter the notes that are already listed, not show the notes outside the filter.

I deployed it => https://take-notesw.surge.sh/

```
return (
     <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={6} marginTop="2">
         {
             filterText &&
             Array(notes).filter(note =>
                 note.title?.toLocaleLowerCase()
                     .includes(filterText)
                     .map(filteredNote => (
                         <Box
                             key={filteredNote.id}
                             bg="gray.100"
                             w="100%"
                             h="100px"
                             overflow="auto"
                             textAlign="center"
                         >
                             <Text fontSize="18px" bg={handleNoteColor(filteredNote.color)}>Note {filteredNote.id}</Text>
                             <Text fontSize="13px">{filteredNote.title}</Text>
                         </Box>
                        ))
                )
         }
         {
             !filterText &&
             notes.map((note) => (
                 <Box
                     key={note.id}
                     bg="gray.100"
                     w="100%"
                     h="100px"
                     overflow="auto"
                     textAlign="center"
                 >
                     <Text fontSize="18px" bg={handleNoteColor(note.color)}>Note {note.id}</Text>
                     <Text fontSize="13px">{note.title}</Text>
                 </Box>
          ))
      }
  </Grid >
)
```

Comment: Please add what is the code supposed to actually do and what it is doing?

Comment: No, it won't, Lodash won't fix this issue and a simple filter is a pointless use case for Lodash.
It looks to me like you want to render notes that contain the `filterText`. If so I'll write  out the answer for that :)

Comment: Misplaced brackets. You are doing the `.map` ***within*** the `.filter`. You probably meant to do it ***after*** the `.filter`.... ie `.filter(...).map(...)`

Comment: The parentheses are not properly used. You're trying to use map on includes

Comment: I would be easier if you provide a sandbox. But I don't understand why do you use `Array(notes)`, is `notes` an array? or are you trying to create an array there? Maybe you miss the `new` keyword before Array?

Comment: First of all, I added the missing parenthesis as you said, but there was no change. 
@Nat The reason I did this was because it gave an error. Actually notes is an array, it contains id, title and color fields and initially it has 4 elements.

Comment: May I ask what error did you get? If notes is an array everything should be fine, may I suggest adding a condition `note.isArray()`? it should be ` filterText && note.isArray() && notes.filter(note =>........`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a misplaced parentheses. You're missing a `)` after the `includes` and have instead placed that extra `)` after the map.

```
return (
     <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={6} marginTop="2">
         {
             filterText &&
             Array(notes)
               .filter(note =>  
                     note.title?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterText)
               )
               .map(filteredNote => (...))
         }
         {
             !filterText &&
             notes.map((note) => (...))
         }
  </Grid>
)
```

Comment: No idea what you're referring to, but he removed the comment now

Comment: @ChrisG I added a little changes on this solution and the error was resolved. That's why I deleted the comment.